# Why an open descriptor is not closed on program exit?

Tags: c, linux, busybox

I have a small program below on 2.6.16-rc3, which uses busy box (on jffs2 file system). 
If I run the program multiple times, it starts to fail second time onwards . When the program quits, the descriptors shall be auto closed and next time it shall start fresh , right ?

Why I am getting -1 some times? (Note - On my Fedora Linux PC , it works fine)

```
root@badge 07:29:32 ~ >touch Hello.txt
root@badge 07:29:37 ~ >./a.out
FP = 3
root@badge 07:29:38 ~ >./a.out
FP = -1
root@badge 07:29:40 ~ >./a.out
FP = 3
root@badge 07:29:41 ~ >./a.out
FP = -1
root@badge 07:29:42 ~ >./a.out
FP = 3
root@badge 07:29:43 ~ >./a.out
FP = 3
root@badge 07:29:43 ~ >./a.out
FP = -1
root@badge 07:29:45 ~ >
```

### Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        int fp;
        fp = open ("Hello.txt");
        printf("FP = %d\n", fp);
        return 0;  // No close() is used. On exit, it shall be closed.
}
```

### Text File:

```
    -rw-r--r--    1 root     root            0 Sep 20 07:22 Hello.txt
```

Comment: Are you getting any warnings while compiling this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not following the contract of the `open()` call. The man page (on Linux) states this:

```
SYNOPSIS
       #include <sys/types.h>
       #include <sys/stat.h>
       #include <fcntl.h>

       int open(const char *pathname, int flags);
       int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);

       int creat(const char *pathname, mode_t mode);
```

As you can see, you're forgetting to include the right headers, and `open()` also takes a flags parameter where you would state read/write rights, etc. As this is laid out you'll get a mystery argument passed to `open()`, this is whatever was on the stack or in the registers at the time.

Comment: Although he would pass something strange, doesn't the operating system ensure that all descriptors belonging to a process are destroyed on program termination?

Comment: @Blagovest: it does, but the fact of the fd being closed doesn't guarantee that it can be opened in future. The questioner has assumed that it fails because it's already open, Maister says that it fails because of the garbage arguments.